# Does every non-elementary subgroup of the additive group of rationals contain prime multiples of elements in its complement?

Tags: group-theory

> Let $H$ be a non-elementary proper subgroup of $(\Bbb Q,+)$, the
>   additive group of rational numbers. Then there exists an element $a$
>   in $\Bbb Q\setminus H$ such that $p\cdot a$ is in $H$ for some prime
>   number $p$.

I have not been able to prove this. I'm looking to see if someone else out there has any advice. Anything would be appreciated. 
If it turns out to be false I'd be happy to see a disproof of course. 
Thank you.

Comment: Where did this problem arise?

Comment: @Shaun it's in a book on group theory. The author states it without proof, then uses it to prove the additive group of rationals contains only subgroups of infinite index.

Comment: Okay, @TimEller; which book?

Comment: @Shaun Theory of Groups by A. G. Kurosh

Comment: @Shaun did you edit my post? I have a question about the edit.

Comment: [I didn't edit it,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHHGk.jpg) @TimEller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\frac mn\in \mathbb Q/H$  with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and let $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$ be the prime factorization of $n$. We multiply by one of the $p_i$ after another.  If we get to an element in $H$ we are done, otherwise we can assume that this process leads to an integer $r \in \mathbb Q/H$.

Let $s\in H\cap \mathbb Z$. (Note: if $\frac lk\in H$ then $l\in H\cap \mathbb Z$.) Then of course $sr\in H$.  If $s=\prod q_i^{b_i}$ is the prime factorization of $s$, then we divide $sr$ by each $q_i$ in turn until we get to an element not in $H$.

Comment: Thanks for answering